# Laravel site exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException'

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, csrf

Laravel 5.1

I'm getting this error occasionally, most often on log in on IE11 but sometimes on AJAX calls too. I have the appropriate csrf fields in my log in form and I've also added it to the AjaxSetup function.

I think it's happening with ajax because the users are coming back to the page after a while and trying to use a function after their session has expired.

The IE11 issue confuses me though since they're logged out already.

1. How can I automatically redirect to login when an ajax function is uses after session has expired?
2. What can I do to prevent IE11 from generating this error when trying to log in?

.

```
Error of type ERROR [03/02/2016 11:06 am]: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' on page /var/www/vendor/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 /var/www/vendor/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9585): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/vendor/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(12961): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 /var/www/vendor/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9585): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/vendor/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(11555): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#7 /var/www/vendor/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9585): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/vendor/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(12698): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 /var/www/vendor/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9585): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /var/www/vendor/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(12635): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /var/www/vendor/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9585): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/vendor/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2982): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 /var/www/vendor/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9585): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /var/www/vendor/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9575): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /var/www/vendor/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2254): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#20 /var/www/vendor/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2237): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /var/www/vendor/public/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a CSRF token for your ajax request as well as form posts. Make sure to include the token or for all the routes under web group middleware.

You can achieve this creating a meta tag in your header.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

and include this token into your ajax calls. (Your ajax request may look different but should have _token in the data.)

var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, data:data},
   dataType: 'JSON',
   url: "/check",
   success: function(msg){ 
         //something...  
   }); 
});
```

and for the form posts you can include the code below inside your forms.

`{{ csrf_field() }}`

Comment: I've got this in my head `<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>` I'll try changing the name

Comment: this shouldn't have made a difference because the `$.ajaxSetup` function was using the the name `_token` too.

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as the name's are matching. Have you check the forms to make sure they have the token field?

Comment: Yes the login and register forms have the field added. I should have mentioned I get almost 0 problems on Firefox and Chrome. It's mostly in IE11.

Comment: almost 0 problems doesn't sound right. It should be 0 problems. Can you post some code? For example the view that gets you logout?

Comment: Sorry It's taken me so long to respond. When I said almost 0 problems I meant that the only problem Firefox and Chrome have are when it's through ajax. I believe the issue is a session caching problem on IE11. I've decided to just redirect to login if there's a token mismatch but I'm having trouble with that too which I'll post a second question about.